# Didn't get multiple checked checkbox on button click and on load page : ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

On page load I checked few of check boxes . using following code

```
 <li ng-repeat="template in alltest" >

                <input type="checkbox" name="template" ng-model="template.isselected" value="{{template.id}}" id="{{template.id}}" ng-checked="isChecked(template.id)">
                <label for="{{template.id}}" class="position-relative"><span></span>
                </label> 


            </li>
```

isChecked function

```
 $scope.isChecked = function(id){
            var match = false;
            if($scope.alltest!=null)
            {
            for(var i=0 ; i < $scope.alltest.length; i++) {
             if($scope.alltest[i].tmp_id == id){
                match = true;
            }  
            }

          }
      return match;
  };
```

When I click on button to get those checkboxes then didn't get those check boxes

```
angular.forEach($scope.alltest, function(template){
                              if (template.isselected)
                              {
                               alert(template.id)
                              } 
                            })
```

If I again deselected those check boxes and again select then i get value..but on page load by default few of check boxes coming with true option and directly i click on submit button then didn't get those checked check box

what is wrong with this code? please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

ng-model is defult **undefined**. When checkbox is checked ng-model create property. that is why you get only checked checkbox when form submitted. You need define false checkboxes also inside isChecked function

```
ng-checked="isChecked(template.id, $index)">
```

js

```
$scope.isChecked = function(id, index) {
  var match = false;
  if ($scope.alltest != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.alltest.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.alltest[i].tmp_id == id) {
        match = true;
      }
    }

  }
  if (!match) $scope.alltest[index].isselected = false
  return match;
};
```

Comment: its not working...when i  checked checkboxes in one page and navigate to other page then i got checked those checkboxes in other page..but when i click on button on other page then didn't get those cheked checkboxes....

Comment: i think you need add id on your model `ng-model="template.isselected[template.id]"`

Comment: I did those changes but still not getting values of selected checkbox..I can checkboxes are selected but not getting those value...If i deselect and again select then got value...but without that i can not any other solution please appreciated